# Have WSDL, need to generate services (step by step instructions)

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, spring-ws

Any documentation on creating a service and deploy to JBoss from WSDL?  I have found several on the net, struggling to choose the correct/optimal approach.  Using spring is also okay.

I have created WSDL from eclipse based on my requirements.  Now, How do i generate request/response from WSDL?  and then stubs.  I also can use Intellij if it simplifies things.

I did generate a service, but i had to strip out so many jar files (jboss related) from my ear file before deploying to make it work.  Any help generating ear file will be helpful too.

JDK 1.6; JBoss 5.1; Eclipse Indigo or Intellij Idea (11.1.4)

I know this question has been asked several times, but as i mentioned tons of information on the web, getting confused with several approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can use the [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) to generate artifacts. You can find a simple maven project for generating artifacts from a WSDL, [here (wsimport)](https://github.com/nazartm/quickstarts)

Step-by-step:

1. Generate Java artifacts from your WSDL. (Use [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool or Maven plugin)
2. Implement the generated Service Endpoint Interface.
3. Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with Spring-WS, the obvious starting point is [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html). You probably want to use a marshalling framework like JAXB to generate classes based on your WSDL. Based on those classes you can create `@Endpoint` annotated classes. In such an endpoint, you can create methods which are annotated with `@PayloadRoot` and `@RequestPayLoad` - based on that combination it will be mapped to a specific operation in the WSDL. Check out [this page](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-atEndpoint-methods) in the documentation for more information on annotating methods.

Comment: three things i got confused.. 1) in the documentation link you provided, the step (3.6.1. Handling the XML Message) is not realistic.  I don't think this should be a way for real time projects. This is where JAXB come into picture?  2) With JAXB, i generated the classes, but it puts all the classes in one specific package.  Do we have to move the classes every time to respective packages after generation?  How do we deal with it if wsdl change?  3) Also need some information about how can i package the stuff to war or ear.

Comment: **1** Probably it's not the way to go, that's indeed where Jaxb or any other marshalling framework comes in. Check out chapter 5 of the docs for more info. You can find examples in the zip package from the download page.
**2** If you create the files with xjc, you can use the `-p <pkg>` parameter to specifiy the package. When using the jaxb2-maven-plugin, you can use `<packageName>` in pom.xml.
**2.1** When the WSDL changes you will have to build the classes again.
**3** Use maven, for instance: a seperate project which generates the JAXB classes which is included in the war or ear project.